# Add favicon to websites that do not already have them Safari

Tags: macos, safari, favicon

When I launch Safari to the favorites page, most of the websites I have saved do not have favicons. They instead show one letter in the box. Is there a way I could add my own favicons for these websites?

Thank You,
OMEGALORD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The favicon is a website specific icon, if the website did not have one, your bookmark will not have one.

If a website updates their favicon, you might need need to refresh the cache.

So unless you were to install a browser extension to allow you to pick your own icons then I doubt you will have much success with this.